# C++ pathfinding with a-star, optimization

Tags: c++, path-finding, a-star

Im wondering if I can optimize my pathfinding code a bit, lets look at this map:

```
+ - wall, . - free, S - start, F - finish
.S.............
...............
..........+++..
..........+F+..
..........+++..
...............
```

The human will look at it and say its impossible, becouse finish is surrounded... But A-star MUST check all fields to ascertain, that there isnt possible road. Well, its not a problem with small maps. But when I have 256x265 map, it takes a lot of time to check all points. I think that i can stop searching while there are closed nodes arround the finish, i mean:

```
+ - wall, . - free, S - start, F - finish, X - closed node
.S.............
.........XXXXX.
.........X+++X.
.........X+F+X.
.........X+++X.
.........XXXXX.
```

And I want to finish in this situation (There is no entrance to "room" with finish). I thought to check h, and while none of open nodes is getting closer, then to finish... But im not sure if its ok, maybe there is any better way?

Thanx for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this problem is better solved with [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), but I will assume you have a good reason to use a-star instead. However I still recommend you first check the connectivity between S and F with some kind of search(Breadth-first or depth-first search). This will solve our issue.

Comment: so you mean I have to check if there is ANY road between S and F and then search for shortest?

Comment: In fact BFS will find the shortest road anyway. If you choose DFS you will just check if there is any road, yes.

Comment: I havent heard anything about BFS and DFS, I choose A*, becouse I heard its fast on big maps. Will it be faster to use DFS and then A*, or just BFS?

Comment: The best solution of this problem is using BFS and it will be as fast as possible.

Comment: Well, Its too hard for me. Im just 15... It was hard to implement A*, but I dont understand BFS and DFS at all. I think I gonna find a way to check if F isnt in closed "room". Anyway, great thanks for your help.

Comment: @kittyPL: BFS is simpler than A*, it's just A* without the weight heuristic. So it will be faster if there's no path and it scans the whole map. **However**, the whole point of A* is that it is *much faster* than BFS when a path exists. It's up to you to decide what is the "common case". Probably you're better to assume that usually there is a path and continue using A*.

Comment: I do think that in most case the road exists, so I will still use A*. If you can help me a bit in checking if Finish is surrounded by closed node, I will be pleased.

Comment: @kittyPL: I guess you can't do it efficiently. see my answer for a possible optimization (with tradeoffs).

Comment: Implementing BFS in this case is quite easy if you have the right aproach. It may be true that A* will be faster in some(possibly most cases), but it has certain drawbacks: it does not gurantee that the path found is minimal and the case you mentioned- it can not handle well cases where there is no path at all.

Comment: @izomorphius: What? O.o A\* finds the best solution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A\*_search_algorithm#Properties).

Comment: @ybungalobill yes, my mistake. Still it is possible that A* is even slower then BFS in some cases and also you can not handle the case when you don't have a solution at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the map doesn't change, you can preprocess it by dividing it to [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29). It can be done with a fast [disjoint set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Then before launching A* you check in constant time that the source and destination belong to the same component. If not—no path exists, otherwie you run A* to find the path.

The downside is that you will need additional n-bits per cell where n = ceil(log C) for C being the number of connected components. If you have enough memory and can afford it then it's OK.

Edit: in case you fix n being small (e.g. one byte) and have more than that number of components (e.g. more than 256 for 8-bit n) then you can assign the same number to multiple components. To achieve best results make sure each component-id has nearly the same number of cells assigned to it.

Comment: But in order to compute the connected components you need to run a search(for instance BFS) and once you've ran BFS you already have the answer - I see no reason why you would use A*.

Comment: @izomorphius: It's a reprocessing step (done just once for the whole map).

Comment: Ahh you mean for multiple queries. In that case yes, this will speed up the things.

Comment: O.o I dont understand at all. I just need to add that the map will change during game... But then I can just merge the tow cell sets...

Comment: @ybungalobill How can I connect/extend sets when something changes value?

Comment: @kittyPL: My answer starts with "assuming the map doesn't change". There are more complicated data structures for changing sets too. However it doesn't worth the optimization.